# MySQL backup database

Tags: mysql

I tried to backup the database from my mysql server.

I am using MYSQL 5.5.

I used the following Command to backup the database.

```
            $ mysqldump -root -admin project > projectbackup.sql
```

My username: root, 
Password : admin,
database name : project

But it showing the following error. as like as the following screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Not sure if you can use redirect `>` sign on Windows OS.

Answer (score 9):

try with this in command prompt not in mysql prompt

```
 mysqldump -u root -p admin project > projectbackup.sql
```

[Docs](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/mysql/dump-mysql-database-schema)

Comment: I opened Command Prompt. and i enter the above command. But it showing "Access is Denied"

Comment: mysqldump -root -admin project > projectbackup.sql

My User Name : root

My Password : admin

Database Name : project

Comment: okies.. update with full error message in post please.. try with spaces between username and paswword ..and lets know if any issues there

Comment: reason is you are trying to provide password in first type itself not space, mysqldump -u root -p project > backup.sql should work

Answer (score 5):

From what I remember, mysqldump is a program, not a MySQL command.  Run it from the Windows command prompt instead of the MySQL prompt.  Also, don't include the $ dollar sign.

Also you'll need to include the username and password with --user=Your_user_name_here --password=Your_password_here

Documented usage here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: I opened Command Prompt. and i enter the above command. But it showing "Access is Denied"

Answer (score 4):

Try this `mysqldump -uroot -p project > projectbackup.sql`.

Now when prompted for password type "admin"

Answer (score 2):

Open up a Windows command prompt.

```
Click Start -> Run
Enter “cmd” into the dialog box and click the “OK” button.
```

Change the directory to the following to access the mysqldump utility.

```
cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin
```

Create a dump of your current mysql database or table (do not include the bracket symbols [ ] in your commands).

Run the mysqldump.exe program using the following arguments:

```
mysqldump.exe –e –u[username] -p[password] -h[hostname] [database name] > C:\[filename].sql
```

Answer (score 2):

To backup my DB, I use these three commands (in a batch file):

```
mysqladmin -u root -pMyPassword drop backupExample --force=true
mysqladmin -u root -pMyPassword create backupExample
mysqldump -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -pMyPassword DBExample | mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -pMyPassword backupExample
```

where:

"**DBExample**" is the name of the DB to backup

"**backupExample**" is the new db that will be created as a copy

"**MyPassword**" is your db password

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Unable to comment on the answer by @Thanga so posting it separately.

There should be a space between -u and root. Likewise for -p and admin. So the command would look like:

```
mysqldump -u root -p admin project
```

Answer (score 0):

The mysqldump command accesses a program and is not called in the mysql command prompt.

It basically does a big `SELECT * FROM tables...` query and echos the output in your terminal, which is why you redirect the output to save it to a file.

You need to find the direct path to the `mysqldump.exe` file and then execute it that way.

`C:\...\path\to\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe -uroot -p DATABASE_SCHEMA > C:\backup.txt`

Only include the `-p` flag if your mysql root user account has a password and replace the `DATABASE_SCHEMA` text with what your database name is called.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ mysqldump -uroot -padmin project > project.sql
```