# Backup database in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-backups

I'm currently learning sql. I'm running mysql 8.0.16 cli on Windows 10 cmd and I'm logged in as root mysql user and running the cmd as administrator.
What I would like to do is a backup of my newly created db.

This is my SHOW DATABASES output:

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| learnsql           |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is:

```
backup database learnsql to disk = 'E:\backup.bak';
```

The output I get is:

```
mysql> backup database learnsql to disk = 'E:\backup.bak';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'backup database learnsql to disk = 'E:\backup.bak'' at line 1
```

The path I'm providing is valid. My guess is that MySql does not support "backup database" command, but shouldn't it be in the Sql standard?

EDIT: I know I can use sqldump to to do the same thing, but I'm learning and would really like to understand why this specific command is invalid.

Comment: backup database is unique to mssql in my experience. easiest way is to just use mysqldump

Comment: @dprogramz I'd put that as an answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL backup database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13427381/mysql-backup-database)

Comment: @SamM I know I can do it with sqldump. What I'm really interested about is why this specific command is not working(for learning purposes). If @ dprogramz 's answer is correct, that's all I need to know

Comment: What makes you think that this is a valid command? You can't simply make them up and complain they don't work

Comment: @NicoHaase I was walking through a tutorial on W3School: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_backup_db.asp

Comment: Well, that's a tutorial for SQL server, as written on that very page. MySQL is not the same as SQL server

Comment: @NicoHaase That's it. I didn't notice that. I'm aware that they are not the same and will read more carefully next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL Standard is a large, academic document, and - to the best of my knowledge - [not available for free on the web](https://modern-sql.com/standard).

What should and should not be in the standard is a complex topic, and many actual databases don't implement the standard for years (or at all). Most of the energy for the standard goes into supporting features for software development and design, such as support for object mapping, temporal and spatial features; backups etc. are mostly operational concerns. Backups are also likely to be very implementation-specific, and the standard tries to be agnostic of specific implementation detail.

So, no, the command "backup" is not part of the standard, and probably shouldn't be. Each database engine has its own way of doing this, and it tends to be specific to operating system and underlying database engine.